# MATLAB save each loop output

Tags: matlab

I have a series of arrays ("A", "B", etc.). My program prompts users to select 2 different arrays and it then returns the values common to both.

I want to be able to run this loop multiple times and save the output (ComVal) from each iteration. I've tried using cells but that hasn't been working; I don't know if it's because of the way I've written my code.

```
for k=0;
prompt_a='Select an array: ';
str_a=input(prompt_a);
prompt_b='Select second array: ';
str_b=input(prompt_b);
ComVal=intersect(str_a,str_b);
end
```

Right now if I alter k so I can run it several times, it only saves the final iteration.

Comment: As written your loop only runs once, for `k = 0`, and doesn't use it at all in the loop. As a good primer, take a look at MATLAB's [documentation for loop control](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can save the results into a cell very similar to saving it into a standard array.

```
numIterations = 5;
comVals = cell(1,numIterations)
for k = 1:numIterations
    prompt_a='Select an array: ';
    str_a=input(prompt_a);
    prompt_b='Select second array: ';
    str_b=input(prompt_b);
    comVals{k} = intersect(str_a,str_b);
end
```